# What is the best way to avoid hardcoded keys of Application.Current.Properties?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

In my Xamarin.Forms application, I added a .NET standard library in which I would like to use the Properties dictionary.

However, I would like to avoid the hardcoding of the key "id".

```
Application.Current.Properties ["id"] = someClass.ID;
```

What is the best way to go about it?

Comment: Is my answer targeting your question? I'm not sure, if you asked for what I provided.

Comment: Yes, @Nikolaus Thank you.

Comment: An accepted answer would target my needs. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I would create a static class for this, something along the lines of

```
public static class Constants
    {
        public const string Id = "id";
        // etc...
    }
```

Then update your code to

```
Application.Current.Properties [Constants.Id] = someClass.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no best way, but one way is to use the nameof syntax, because if you rename a Property, this will be changed, too:

```
// I added ToLowerInvariant, because you wrote "id".
Application.Current.Properties[nameof(someClass.ID).ToLowerInvariant()] = someClass.ID;
```